# How to reliably process a list of items using a source list

Tags: redis

Say you need to send out a newsletter.
You have a master list of emails stored in either a list or set (whatever makes sense).

```
List/Set
"user1@example.com"
"user2@example.com"
```

You have may have multiple newsletters being sent out using the same list, so you can't modify the original master list.

In pseudo code I was thinking of this:

1. get x elements, push to "in_progress_123"
2. when consumers are finished processing (success or failure), push to list "completed_123"
3. continue #1 until lists are identical
4. if my server crashes and restarts, it can just continue back to #1

I need a master list, and an "in_progress" list because there can be multiple newsletters being sent out using the same master list.

(note:  I will handle the case of fixing the failure items, but not important for now)

Is this possible with redis?

Maybe I need a combination of both list and sorted sets, but I can't figure out how to do this.  I like RPOPLPUSH but that is for lists, and I need a way to compare lists but that is in sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing lists is expensive and inefficient. Instead consider a different workflow, in which you just duplicate the "master" list and empty it by consuming it with your workers.

Comment: a list may have 100 or 25K emails in it.  How to efficiently duplicate a list?

Comment: Copying will always be proportional to the length, but this is the fastest way I know of: https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/d30b3c40a72a07f23c70

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Benchmarks are something you need to do for yourself.

Comment: btw, what is the NX mean? ```ARGV[1]:upper() == "NX"```

Comment: Basically "not exists" - see the doc for SET: https://redis.io/commands/set